# I can't access phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I install apache on my windows 7 64 bit for phpmyadmin. Downloaded phpMyAdmin-4-0-9-all-languages and extracted and copied in htdocs folder in the appache file and edit confiq index.html to index.php then search on browser localhost/phpmyadmin, it display php files. how could reach the phpmyadmin page

Comment: Try XAMP or WAMP server (All in one packages) Instead of individual installation. http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a package like wamp it is much more easy and automated.